# Vue: template props issue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am new in Vue and I am trying to assign prop values to template...

Here is the template:
CustomInput.vue

```
<template>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="" class="control-label"></label>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input data-val="true" id="" name="" class="form-control" type="text">
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I set value to ,  from the custom tag which is in another file:

Edit.vue

```
<custom-input label-value="Office" label-name="Office" input-id="Office" input-name="Office" :input-v-model="contact.office">Office</custom-input>
```

Comment: Which value do you want to assign? What’s the relationship between the two vue files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is pretty straightforward, so first, I'll link you to the official docs:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props

So, how would this apply to your code?
First of all, you should use `v-bind`, or the shorthand `:`..
if you do that, you would end up doing something like this in your `template`:

```
<label v-bind:id="id" :name="name"> {{ message }} </label>
```

and something like this in your main app, where you import the template:

```
<custom-input :name="yourNameVar" :id="yourIdVar"></custom-input>
```

Now, you head over to your template again and register your props `id` and `name` with this command: `props: [id, name]`.
It is important that the bindings in your `<custom-input>` are the names of the used variables / registered props in your template!

Basically, you could do something like this:

```
<input :id="myShinyIdProperty">
```

Now your template tag would look like this:

```
<your-template-tag :myShinyIdProperty="someVar"></...>
```

This is the correct way of doing stuff with properties, if you want more, consider reading through the entire documentation, link is above..
Vue is awesome ;)